# Angular and data repository pattern

Tags: angular, design-patterns

I've just finished the canonical Heroes tutorial and had a nose around, I'm not a web developer, so there may be something inherent in SPAs that I don't grasp.

Is there a data respository library for Angular/typescript I'm missing?

All the tutorials and walkthrough remind me of 1990s windows application where data is pulled from some database, and then operated on record by record.

In my backend world we would use DbSet<> or datasets and create a relational model, operate on it in locally and then "save" the changes.

Does such a thing exist in this world?...or is there something inherent that makes this pattern not apply?

Comment: NgRx is a data pattern you're looking for. Lots and lots of resources on it.

Comment: Your front application sends request to the backend. The data is pulled from a database by the backend, so your angular front-end application is not responsible for your database connection.

Comment: @codepic...I'll take a look, thanks

Comment: @Florian, I'm not really concerned with database connections.

Comment: hmmm...NgRx seems much bigger than I was expecting...I'm simply expecting some sort of façade with lists of relational data

Comment: This is very good question. I don't know why it gets down votes. Repository pattern has nothing to database util it's used to pull the data from it. It's about giving a nice, meaningful facade to your collections. So for example you can have heroesRepository with methods add, findById etc. that gives you this nice abstraction layer over nasty find, findIndex, splice etc.

Answer (score 0):

i seem to be getting markdowns, but with no reason why!

i wondered whether this was a really stupid question of a noob, and then i stumbled on things like redux-orm...and realised I wasnt barking up completely the wrong tree.

So my answer for now, for others is...

look at redux-orm, there may be others.